# WARNING:tensorflow: Compiled the loaded model, but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. model.compile_metrics will be empty until

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run video captioning on tensorflow. However, when I attempt to run `train.py` I am getting this warning and the problem is that the saved models `encoder_model.h5` and decoder`_model_weights.h5` are  remain the same size no matter how many epoch you set (even epoch = 500) and the system performance is too bad at predicting. I think there is an error in the way to save the model. Can any one help me please.

training function:

```
 def train_model(self):
        """
        an encoder decoder sequence to sequence model
        reference : https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00487
        """
        encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(config.time_steps_encoder, config.num_encoder_tokens), name="encoder_inputs")
        encoder = LSTM(config.latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, name='encoder_lstm')
        _, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
        encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

        decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(config.time_steps_decoder, config.num_decoder_tokens), name="decoder_inputs")
        decoder_lstm = LSTM(config.latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='decoder_lstm')
        decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
        decoder_dense = Dense(config.num_decoder_tokens, activation='relu', name='decoder_relu')
        decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

        model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
        # model.summary()
        training_list, validation_list = self.preprocessing()

        train = self.load_dataset(training_list)
        valid = self.load_dataset(validation_list)

        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, mode='min')

        # Run training
        opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0003)
        reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss",
                                                      factor=0.1, patience=5, verbose=0,
                                                      mode="auto")
        model.compile(metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

        validation_steps = len(validation_list)//self.batch_size
        steps_per_epoch = len(training_list)//self.batch_size

        model.fit(train, validation_data=valid, validation_steps=validation_steps,
                  epochs=self.epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                  callbacks=[reduce_lr]) # , early_stopping
 
        if not os.path.exists(self.save_model_path):
            os.makedirs(self.save_model_path)

        self.encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
        decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
        decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
            decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
        decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
        decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
        self.decoder_model = Model(
            [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
            [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
        # self.encoder_model.summary()
        # self.decoder_model.summary()




        # saving the models
        self.encoder_model.save( os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'encoder_model.h5'))
        self.decoder_model.save_weights(os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'decoder_model_weights.h5'))
        with open(os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'tokenizer' + str(self.num_decoder_tokens)), 'wb') as file:
            joblib.dump(self.tokenizer, file)
```

---

output of running `trian.py` for 5 epoch:

```
C:\Users\MSI\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\adam.py:110: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super(Adam, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
Epoch 1/5

2022-09-07 19:36:09.455987: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-09-07 19:36:10.160168: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3497 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2022-09-07 19:36:21.205093: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8401
2022-09-07 19:36:22.038099: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1786] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
245/245 [==============================] - 32s 112ms/step - loss: 5.7208 - accuracy: 0.2957 - val_loss: 5.3780 - val_accuracy: 0.3274 - lr: 3.0000e-04
Epoch 2/5
245/245 [==============================] - 27s 111ms/step - loss: 5.2917 - accuracy: 0.3304 - val_loss: 5.3651 - val_accuracy: 0.3324 - lr: 3.0000e-04
Epoch 3/5
245/245 [==============================] - 27s 112ms/step - loss: 5.2468 - accuracy: 0.3328 - val_loss: 5.2229 - val_accuracy: 0.3407 - lr: 3.0000e-04
Epoch 4/5
245/245 [==============================] - 28s 113ms/step - loss: 5.1038 - accuracy: 0.3347 - val_loss: 4.9872 - val_accuracy: 0.3355 - lr: 3.0000e-04
Epoch 5/5
245/245 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.9417 - accuracy: 0.3367 WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 43 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
245/245 [==============================] - 28s 115ms/step - loss: 4.9417 - accuracy: 0.3367 - val_loss: 4.8479 - val_accuracy: 0.3398 - lr: 3.0000e-04
WARNING:tensorflow:Compiled the loaded model, but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. `model.compile_metrics` will be empty until you train or evaluate the model.
C:\GGGGGGGG\Projects\Video_captioning_shyne _updated\train.py:94: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  train_sequences = np.array(train_sequences)
```

Comment: Please try again by removing the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` from `model.fit()`. You can mention the `batch_size` inside `model.fit()` which will automatically calculate the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` as per mentioned `batch_size`.